# Gerar um PDF baseado em um HTML

Tags: html, ios, pdf

Estou precisando gerar um PDF em um app IOS baseado em um HTML. Tenho o código HTML gerado em outra linguagem e preciso reescrever o código para IOS.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de quais as bibliotecas ou objetos devo usar para as duas coisas? Gerar o HTML e depois o PDF?

Comment: Pesquisei rapidamente aqui e encontrei essa lib. Não sei se é o que você está a procurar: https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf

Comment: Uma dúvida, que outra linguagem gera esse html pra você? É server side? Se sim, por que o próprio server não gera o pdf para você?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar o código sugerido pelo Otávio no comentário. Testei e o código é muito simples e prático.

[github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf](http://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf)